# When do we need Dx12 Descriptors to be contiguous?

Tags: rendering, directx12

In many tutorials and examples code of DirectX 12 we can find ways to manage descriptors by creating a few descriptor heaps and allocating manually descriptors inside of them
(e.g. in Mini Engine the `DescriptorHeap` class or the `DescriptorAllocator` in the excellent 3dgep tutorial).

So far every example I found on the web does support allocation of `n` continuous descriptors and therefore implement a non trivial allocator to support it. However all the call sites where several descriptors are allocated at once seems more like a convenience than a requirement since each individual descriptors is then bound individually later in the code.

I don't really understand in which case we *do* need to have continuous descriptors, other than possible cache friendliness.

Is there specific feature or cases where it's required to have several descriptors next to each others ?

The examples I found:

- Mini Engine `DescriptorHeap`: https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/MiniEngine/Core/DescriptorHeap.h#L33
- 3dgep `DescriptorAllocator`: https://www.3dgep.com/learning-directx-12-3/#DescriptorAllocator_Class
- bgfx `DescriptorAllocator`: https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/blob/master/src/renderer_d3d12.h#L173
- The-Forge `DescriptorHeap`: https://github.com/ConfettiFX/The-Forge/blob/master/Common_3/Graphics/Direct3D12/Direct3D12.cpp#L397
- Dilligent Graphics: http://diligentgraphics.com/diligent-engine/architecture/d3d12/managing-descriptor-heaps/